# Need a bit of help defining some methods

Tags: ruby, class, object

I would really appreciate it if I could get some help on some questions regarding an assignment that prints out the data typed in by a user(In this specific example, the year, model, and make of the car):

```
# DEFINE YOUR CAR CLASS HERE

# create empty array
array_of_cars = Array.new 

# prompt for and get number of cars
print "How many cars do you want to create? "
 num_cars = gets.to_i

# create that many cars
for i in 1..num_cars 
# get the make, model, and year
puts
print "Enter make for car #{i}: "
make = gets.chomp

print "Enter model for car #{i}: "
model = gets.chomp

print "Enter year of car #{i}: "
year = gets.to_i

# create a new Car object
c = Car.new

# set the make, model, and year
# that we just read in
c.set_make(make)
c.set_model(model)
c.set_year(year)

# add the Car object to the array
array_of_cars << c 
end 

# print out the information for 
# the Car objects in the array
puts
puts "You have the following cars: " 

for car in array_of_cars 
puts "#{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}" 
end
```

I already have some part of the program, but struggle with the main portion of it, since I kind of know what to do but not how to implement it.

So for this part: # DEFINE YOUR CAR CLASS HERE

I got this:

```
class Car

def assign(m,n,y)
    #instance variables
    @make = m
    @model = n
    @year = y
end
    #instance methods
def set_make

end

def set_model

end

def set_year

end

def get_make

end

def get_model

end

def get_year

end
```

First, did I do it right with the instance variables?

And then, the purpose of "set" is to save the value into the array right? and then "get" allows me to extract them later. I think I would understand the concept if someone could show me how to define one of them.

I know that this seems a bit vague, so I will try my best to clarify if some questions occur. Also sorry for the wall of text and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, in “idiomatic ruby” we call getters and setters for `@variable` as `variable` (getter) and `variable=` (setter.) The constructor is to be named `initialize`, not `assign`.

There is a helper to define both for the class, [`Module#attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) that declares both getter and setter under the hood, so that your class definition might be as short as:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model, :year

  def initialize(make, model, year)
    @make = make
    @model = model
    @year = year
  end
end
```

So far so good. The rest of your code would be:

```
array_of_cars = [] # use Array.new with parameter, [] otherwise

# prompt for and get number of cars
print "How many cars do you want to create? "
num_cars = gets.to_i

# create that many cars
(1..num_cars).each do |i| # in idiomatic ruby, never use for loops
  # get the make, model, and year
  puts "Enter make for car #{i}: "
  make = gets.chomp

  print "Enter model for car #{i}: "
  model = gets.chomp

  print "Enter year of car #{i}: "
  year = gets.to_i

  # create a new Car object
  c = Car.new(make, model, year)

  # add the Car object to the array
  array_of_cars << c 
end 

# print out the information for 
# the Car objects in the array
puts
puts "You have the following cars: " 

array_of_cars.each do |car|
  puts "#{car.year} #{car.make} #{car.model}" 
end
```

BTW, instead of pre-creating an array, one might better use [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
# prompt for and get number of cars
print "How many cars do you want to create? "
num_cars = gets.to_i

# ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓  DECLARE IT IN-PLACE
array_of_cars = (1..num_cars).map do |i|
  puts "Enter make for car #{i}: "
  make = gets.chomp

  print "Enter model for car #{i}: "
  model = gets.chomp

  print "Enter year of car #{i}: "
  year = gets.to_i

  # create a new Car object
  Car.new(make, model, year)
end
```

That would produce an array needed out of the box.

---

**Addendum:** to define getter and setter manually:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :make, :model

  def initialize(make, model, year)
    @make = make
    @model = model
    @year = year
  end

  # manually declare getter for year:
  def year
    @year
  end
  # manually declare setter for year:
  def year=(year)
    @year = year
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you so much for your response, however, let's say I do not want to use attr_accessor. How would the more "complicated" approach look like with a getter and setter individually defined in the class? If you don't mind, I would greatly appreciate it if you could demonstrate one of the examples. So for instance if I have: c.set_make(make), how would it be defined in the class?

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day sir